How to Cancel Multiple Orders in Magento 2 Using a Single API Call
I'm looking for a way to cancel multiple orders at once via Magento 2 REST API. The standard approach I know is: POST /V1/orders/{order_id}/cancel
However, this endpoint processes orders one at a time, which makes it very slow for bulk operations when I have a large number of orders to cancel.
Is there any native method or endpoint that allows me to cancel multiple orders in a single API call?

Use Asynchronous web endpoints https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/bulk-endpoints/

Adding async/bulk to your endpoint.
Replace :id by byId.
Json body with multi id items

You should run the bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all to see the result on your local.

